# Run make command on Node project

Tags: node.js, bash, makefile, npm

I have a makefile, Let's say;

```
foo2:
    echo foo2

foo: prefoo
    echo foo


foobar: prefoobar
    echo foobar

all: foo foo2 foobar
```

So I need to run this makefile command on node project. I need run `make foo` or `make foo2` via using my `package.json` file. how can I do that? can I write it below ?

> "scripts": {  "foo": "make foo",  "foo2": "make foo2" }

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> So I need to run this makefile command on node project. I need run make foo or make foo2 via using my package.json file. how can I do that? can I write it below ?
>
> ```
> "scripts": { "foo": "make foo", "foo2": "make foo2" }
> ```

You can, and it will work as you want. In fact, [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples) contain this example of running Make in `npm` scripts:

> If you want to run a make command, you can do so. This works just fine:
>
> ```
> { "scripts" :
>   { "preinstall" : "./configure"
>   , "install" : "make && make install"
>   , "test" : "make test"
>   }
> }
> ```

One thing to keep in mind is that `npm` and Make manage dependencies differently:

- `npm` won't look for lifecycle dependencies in Makefile automatically: you have to define `{ "prefoo": "make prefoo" }` if you intend `prefoo` to run before `foo` by `npm`;
- Make has no implicit recipes for running `npm` scripts, so you need to add something like this if you want Make to run `npm` for some of its goals:

  ```
  prefoo:
      npm run prefoo
  ```